# Windows - how can I run a Python file in any cmd directory?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have a Python script focused on automating the creation of a repository in github, to execute it I write

```
py repo.py --name reponame
```

This works in `cmd.exe` but only in the directory where the file is, I want it to work anywhere, the tutorial on which I base it does it in linux, I have investigated but I have not found anything

Comment: python /home/.../xxx.py -name reponame

Comment: you can make it [Command Line Scripts](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well first you have to turn it into an executable
by using pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

open the main directory

```
pyinstaller --onefile your-script.py
```

then copy the executable from the `dist` folder into a folder added into the `PATH`

example:

```
C:\Windows
```

or add the custom folder into the PATH
from `Control Panel\System and Security\System`
and then `Advanced system settings`
, `Environment Variables`
and then `system variables`
and then edit the `PATH` with your path

and then you can execute it from any directory

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this in Windows. You can type the full
path to the python executable, as in

```
c:/pythonX/python c:/Scripts/xx.py
```

Or

You’ll have to make sure Python is added to **Path** which is a list of
system directories that Windows will look in automatically if you try to run an executable file directly from the command line.

To do this open up the *Control Panel* and navigate to *System| Advanced System Settings*. Under the *Advanced* tab click on *Environment Variables*. Then highlight *Path* in the system variables area, then click *Edit*. Click *New*, and add C:\PythonX\ to the list. Click *OK* and close. That should allow you to run Python scripts from cmd without specifying the full path.